# NoHttpResponseException thrown as runtime exception even though is a checked exception

Tags: java, exception, apache-httpclient-4.x, amazon-sqs

I'm experiencing a strange issue where a `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException` is thrown as unchecked exception even though is a checked exception since it extends `java.io.IOException` ... As it can be seen from the following posted stacktrace I'm getting an exception that should be checked at compile time as an unchecked runtime exception.

The stacktrace of the exception that I get is as follows(my classes are in the package : `com.example.staticsite`) :

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:728)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2419)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1130)
    at com.example.staticsite.aws.SqsReceiverImpl.receiveReceipt(SqsReceiverImpl.java:57)
    at com.example.staticsite.core.processsite.ProcessSiteImpl.runOneTime(ProcessSiteImpl.java:59)
    at com.example.staticsite.core.processsite.ProcessSiteImpl.run(ProcessSiteImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The method that is throwing the exception inside my code is :

```
public class SqsReceiverImpl implements SqsReceiver {
    private AmazonSQS client;
    private String queueUrl;

    @Inject
    public SqsReceiverImpl(AmazonSQS client,@Assisted String queueUrl) {        
        this.client = client;
        this.queueUrl = queueUrl;
    }

    public List<String> receiveReceipt() throws SqsReceiverException {
        if(queueUrl == null)
            throw new SqsReceiverException(SqsReceiverException.MESSAGE_NO_QUEURURL);
        ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
        request.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        request.setQueueUrl(queueUrl);
        request.setWaitTimeSeconds(20);
    
        ReceiveMessageResult results = null;
        try {
            results = client.receiveMessage(request);
        }
        catch(OverLimitException oe){
            throw new SqsReceiverException("OverLimitException thrown");
        }
        catch(AmazonServiceException oe){
            throw new SqsReceiverException("AmazonServiceException thrown");
        }
        catch(AmazonClientException oe){
            throw new SqsReceiverException("AmazonClientException thrown");
        }
```

The `SqsReceiverException` is defined as follows :

```
public class SqsReceiverException extends Exception{

    public SqsReceiverException(String messageNoQueururl) {
        super(messageNoQueururl);
    }
    public static final String MESSAGE_NO_QUEURURL = "Queue url not found. Se the queue url";
}
```

The pom file dependecies are declared as follows :

```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.11</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Producing this results :

[image: Maven dependencies tree]

***How can be possible that this exception is threated as unchecked while it should be checked?
Is there something am I missing here ?***

### Note

*The exception is not always reproducible since it only happens in production when there is a missing response from the Amazon service.*

#### Update

I've verified down the stacktrace till reaching the `AmazonHttpClient` class whereas there is this code that is catching the `IOException' :

```
catch (IOException ioe) {
                if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    log.info("Unable to execute HTTP request: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                }
                captureExceptionMetrics(ioe, awsRequestMetrics);
                awsRequestMetrics.addProperty(AWSRequestID, null);
                AmazonClientException ace = new AmazonClientException(
                        "Unable to execute HTTP request: " + ioe.getMessage(),
                        ioe);
                if (!shouldRetry(request.getOriginalRequest(),
                                p.apacheRequest,
                                ace,
                                p.requestCount,
                                config.getRetryPolicy())) {
                    throw lastReset(ace, request);
                }
                // Cache the retryable exception
                p.retriedException = ace;
            }
```

And the `lastReset` should be the responsible for the exception thrown, what I don't understand is how it is possible that the exception logged is `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException` ...

The line before the stacktrace is always :

```
2017-09-15 07:41:39 INFO  AmazonHttpClient:496 - Unable to execute HTTP request: sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com failed to respond
```

Comment: What flavour of the AmazonSqs client are you using? The Async version?

Comment: Strange indeed because the exception type is also not changing and it is indeed an IOException only. This runs on client side to amazon side?

Comment: It is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, Amazon Red hat linux AMI

Comment: "And the lastReset should be the responsible for the exception thrown, what I don't understand is how it is possible that the exception logged is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException" >> Can you elaborate this? NoHttpResponseException is IOException so it getting catched & logged...

Comment: the exception message: `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com failed to respond` should be `The target server failed to respond` from code. is that message is updated in question?

Comment: @skadya Re: exception message - I think the message is being updated by `DefaultRequestDirector.java:710` on the way back up the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're the victim of stack trace formatting.

I think you're right when you finger `lastReset()` as the culprit.  This is where you see `throws IOException` disappear from the stack trace.  This method is clearly throwing an `AmazonClientException` (a runtime exception), with the original `NoHttpResponseException` "inside" it.

You can simulate this with a snippet like so:

```
throw new AmazonClientException("Oh no!", new NoHttpResponseException("The AWS server doesn't like you"));
```

If I insert this line of code into an existing Java application (Spring Boot, in this case), this is what I see in my Eclipse console:

[image: No sign of the runtime exception]

No sign of the `AmazonClientException`!  Until, I scroll to the right:

[image: There it is]

Amazon made the decision to go with unchecked exceptions, and [documented it here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-exceptions.html).

So they are indeed (I'm pretty sure) wrapping your `IOException` in a runtime exception, to "help" you by giving you "fine-grained control over the errors you handle", although this isn't always obvious.

All that said, I could be wrong.  If I was right, I'd expect to see your custom `SqsReceiverException` at the top of the stack, since you do catch `AmazonClientException`.

It's hard to say for sure without the last few lines from standard out before the stack trace.  If I'm off the mark, could you post them?

***Update***

The line you updated the question with (`AmazonHttpClient:496`) is the line printing the stack trace.  When you pass a `Throwable` to `log.info()`, the stack trace will print.  This trace is being logged **before** your exception is wrapped and re-thrown.

So this bit is seemingly being "swallowed":

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com failed to respond
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:500)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2419)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1130)
    at httptest.Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by:
```

and I can't speak to the missing `SqsReceiverException`.  But I don't think the signature of `DefaultRequestDirector.execute()` is lying, and I don't think we're dealing with a compiler bug.

Perhaps you can add `oe.printStackTrace()` to your `catch (AmazonClientException oe)` block?

Finally, I'd suggest stepping through this with a debugger.  To simulate your production issue, simply set a breakpoint at `DefaultHttpResponseParser:140`, and after this line executes, change `i` to -1.  Then step back up the stack all the way back to your code.

I also set a breakpoint at `AmazonHttpClient:971` so I could change `retries` and avoid going through the loop four times.

Comment: Updated the question at the end with the line that is always before the stacktrace, no other relevant lines are before or after it. I have no `SqsReceiverException` in the log file at all. And this is the strangest thing .

Comment: @aleroot thanks for updating the question.  I've updated my answer accordingly.